# WiX: Paraffin and repository/build server integration

Tags: wix, guid, paraffin

Short version: How can I make sure that my component GUIDs remain stable using Paraffin on a build server?

---

I am currently working on a project that should be deployed via WiX. As this is a web project, it contains many files (still in early stage and already almost 200 files). Also, during development, files are constantly added and deleted, so maintaining the WiX component lists manually is simply not an option.

Since I read a lot about component rules and that people breaking them go to hell, I decided to go with Paraffin as a harvester. This tool is capable of updating an existing component list, thus not re-creating new GUIDs for existing components.

However, when a new component is created, the tool assigns a new GUID. Even if the component files are identical, then initial GUIDs will be different on different machines or even only at different times.

So, obviously, I need a central authority for fixing the initial GUIDs. My idea was to commit empty component lists, which are then filled by the build server calling Paraffin on build. So when I only distribute the MSIs created by the build server, I can be sure that component rules are being followed.

However, the problem with this approach is, that I have no means of tracking my GUIDs, should the build server crash or empty its local repository. I was thinking about having the build server commit the generated component list to my repository, but that doesn't seem like a clean idea.

Another solution I thought of was having all developers build (and thus call Paraffin) before commiting. Thus, each developer would create the initial GUIDs for their newly added files and commit them to the component list.

The obvious problem with this approach: People (e.g. developer A) will forget to build before they commit. So in these cases the build server will create the initial GUIDs for the new files, but those will also only be stored locally. A few commits later, developer B will come along and build the solution, creating a new GUID for the files created by developer A. He will then commit the component list containing this GUID and the build server will check it out. Now the build server has obtained a GUID (created by developer A) for a package, for which it had previously used a different (self-created) GUID, even though the files didn't change in the meantime.

So, how can I make sure, that my GUIDs remain stable between builds without relying on developers to build their solution before they commit? The approaches outlined above both seem unsatisfying to me, but are all I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned component rules only really come into play when you have multiple installers that share components with the same guids (which should then be exactly the same resource(s)) or you are using a wixlib or a merge module which is then included as part of different installers.

From what you have said above, to me it doesn't sound like you will so, there is no harm in having different component guids for each build. It will just mean that when you upgrade the website, files that have not changed will be removed and re-installed under a different component guid. IMHO that doesn't really matter as long as the installer correctly installs all files that are required for the site to function and doesn't remove components from other products.

If you use the [MajorUpgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_majorupgrade.htm) element, the old product will be completely removed before the new one is installed so any component guid's that are shared between the two versions will be removed and then re-installed anyway.

I always just leave my guid elements as `Guid='*'` that way I know that the there will never^ be any guid clashes in any of my components across my multiple products.

^ I know this is not theoretically true but in this use case it is.

Comment: Thank you. Currently, this is probably the way I will be going: Ignoring component rules and simply require users to do a full reinstall instead of an upgrade. Not really an ideal solution, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely true. Changing your component GUIDs from build to build is fine if and only if you schedule RemoveExistingProducts early so that the files are off the system before you reinstall the new GUIDs. This approach works well for smallish installers with not so many files, but as your installer grows you will feel the pinch of having twice as much IO to do, as you remove and then reinstall, rather than just overwrite your files.  In short, it's up to you, but you should think carefully about how large your application is likely to get before jumping in with the suggested approach.